# Проверка на пустую строку

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Привет! Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой.
Получаю с сервера JSON с структурой:

```
{
    response =     {
        items =         (
                        {
                rating = "<null>";
                username = Client;
            }
        );
    };
}
```

Чтобы достать данные, я делаю:

```
NSDictionary *response = [result objectForKey:@"response"];
NSArray *items = [response objectForKey:@"items"];
rating = [[items objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"rating"]; // пробовал и valueForKey
```

Теперь я хочу проверить строку rating, пустой ли он?
Для этого использую:

```
if (![rating isEqual:[NSNull null]] || rating != nil) {
    RatingField.rating = [rating doubleValue];
} else {
    RatingField.rating = 0.0;
}
```

И тут возникает проблема, строка вроде бы пустая, но проходит через условия, что и вызывает ошибку. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то у Вас rating - это string.

Попробуйте:
 if (![rating isEqual:[[NSNull null] description]] || rating != nil)

Comment: "<null>" в логе дикшенари - это NSNull, а не NSString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо || поставь &&

**Update:**

```
[NSNull null] == nil // NO
[NSNull null] == NULL // NO
nil == nil // YES
nil == NULL // YES
```

Comment: и правда. чудеса!
кстати, код: if ([rating isEqual:[NSNull null]] || rating == nil) { RatingField.rating = 0.0; 
} else { RatingField.rating = [rating doubleValue]; } - работает вполне нормально)

Comment: Почему чудеса? :) Все логично. Т.к. [rating isEqual:[NSNull null]] возвращает YES, значение rating == nil If-у уже не интересно. Поэтому срабатывает RatingField.rating = 0.0;
Проверку на rating == nil можно вообще убрать. JSON сериализатор null всегда будет преобразовывать в NSNull, а NSNull, кака я уже писал ранее, не равняется nil

Answer (score 1):

Вот красивое решение

```
#define IS_NOT_EMPTY_STRING(str)  ((str) && [(str) isKindOfClass:NSString.class] && [(str) length] > 0)

if (IS_NOT_EMPTY_STRING(rating)) {
    RatingField.rating = [rating doubleValue];
} else {
    RatingField.rating = 0.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А при `rating = "<null>";` точно null возвращается? У меня серьезные подозрения что возвращается строка `@"<null>`. Кроме того я бы на вашем месте еще проверил не пустая ли там строка (не указатель rating == null, а именно строка -  rating != null; rating.length==0)

Comment: точно не строка, проверял.
Проверка на length - не работает.
Значение равно null.
Что самое интересное, если написать наоборот, т.е.:
if ([rating isEqual:[NSNull null]] || rating == nil) {
    RatingField.rating = 0.0;    
} else {
    RatingField.rating = [rating doubleValue];
} - то все работает нормально.